# How to force run to cursor ignoring other breakpoints in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Sometimes I want to run to a specific line of code ignoring all the checkpoints I've added, but I didn't figure out a way to do this in VSCode.
I've found that this function is available in Visual Studio Preview 2022, but is this function applicable to VSCode? Or is there any alternative to do this?